# Wordpress Search Between two Dates

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I'v created custom post search between two dates. Its working and showing results but there is a one problem. Its not showing exact search results.

for example: if i added 20-3-2013 to 27-3-2013 , its showing wired results of other days and months. its completely not getting exact value.

Here is my code. php

```
<?php
function getCatSearchFilter($pre,$post){
$category = "";
$catId = htmlspecialchars($_GET["cat"]);
if ($catId != null && $catId != '' && $catId != '0'){
$category = $pre.get_cat_name($catId).$post;
}
return $category;
}
?>
    <?php
        $search_word="";

        if(!empty($_REQUEST['s'])){
            $name_word=$_REQUEST['s'];
            $search_word="(post_title LIKE \"%$name_word%\" or post_content LIKE \"%$name_word%\") and ";
        }
        //if(!empty($_REQUEST['d']) && $_REQUEST['d'] != 'von'){
        if(!empty($_REQUEST['sDate'])){
            $s_name_date=$_REQUEST['sDate'];
            $s_custom_date1 = substr($s_name_date,0,2);
            $s_custom_date2 = substr($s_name_date,3,2);
            $s_custom_date3 = substr($s_name_date,6,4);
            $s_name_date = "$s_custom_date3.$s_custom_date2.$s_custom_date1";
            //$search_word.="post_date LIKE \"%$name_date%\" and ";
                        if(!empty($_REQUEST['eDate'])){
                            $e_name_date=$_REQUEST['eDate'];
                            $e_custom_date1 = substr($e_name_date,0,2);
                            $e_custom_date2 = substr($e_name_date,3,2);
                            $e_custom_date3 = substr($e_name_date,6,4);
                            $e_name_date = "$e_custom_date3.$e_custom_date2.$e_custom_date1";
                            //$where .= " AND post_date >= '$s_name_date' AND post_date < '$e_name_date'";
                            $where .= "AND pm.meta_key='custom_time_from' and pm.meta_value >= '$s_name_date'
and pm.meta_value < '$e_name_date'";
                        }
        }
        if($_REQUEST['cat']){
            $categoryId = $_REQUEST['cat'];
            $search_word.="ID in (select p.ID from $wpdb->terms c,$wpdb->term_taxonomy tt,$wpdb->term_relationships tr,$wpdb->posts p ,$wpdb->postmeta t where c.term_id like '".$categoryId."' and c.term_id=tt.term_id and tt.term_taxonomy_id=tr.term_taxonomy_id and tr.object_id=p.ID and p.ID = t.post_id and p.post_status = 'publish' group by p.ID) and";
        }
        if($where)
        {       
        $query ="select p.* from wp_posts p 
join wp_postmeta pm on p.ID=pm.post_id
WHERE p.post_status='publish' and p.post_type='post' $where";   
}
else
{
        $query="select * from wp_posts WHERE $search_word post_status='publish'";
}

    $pageposts=$wpdb->get_results($query, OBJECT);

    if ($pageposts):
    global $post;
    foreach ($pageposts as $post):
    setup_postdata($post);
    ?>
    <?php if($post->post_type=='post')
    {
    ?>
```

here is html

```
        <div id="search">
        <form method="get" id="searchform" action="" >
        <input id="s" style="" type="text" name="s" placeholder="search" value="" />
        <input style="width:95px; " type="text" name="sDate" class="datepicker" placeholder="from" />
        <input style="width:95px;" type="text" name="eDate" class="datepicker" placeholder="to" />
```

Please help to get this work.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You should really consider reading WordPress documents on how to use `$wpdb` and others great functionality it offers.

Comment: This is a lot of code and calls for basic debugging first. Have you looked at which format you are feeding the query your dates - you are aware that the correct format is `YYYY-MM-DD`?

Comment: I check date format issues, its not the problem of date format

Answer (score -1):

```
// Set arguments for events
$start = '2011-11-31';
$end = '2011-10-01';
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'my-event-type',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_key' => '_my-datetime-from',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => '_my-datetime-from',
            'value' => array($start, $end),
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            'type' => 'DATE'
        )
    )
);
// Make the query
$events_query = new WP_query();
$events_query->query($args);
```

Taken from following link

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/34888/how-do-i-search-events-between-two-set-dates-inside-wp